# Bumblebee problem after installation

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, steam, bumblebee, nvidia-prime

Yesterday I was using Kubuntu 13.10. I had a problem using my Intel and Nvidia graphics cards. I thought this was a KDE problem, so I changed distros to Xubuntu. After the installation I installed Steam and it was working. I was happy. I got this error

```
ERROR: Could not open display :8
```

Next I installed an update, and after the update I was trying to install nvidia-prime but after restarting lightdm didn't start. I reinstalled Xubuntu, installed an update, and install the nvidia-319 driver and bumblebee using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-319 nvidia-settings-319
sudo apt-get install bumblebee linux-headers-generic
```

I restarted the computer and installed Steam. After Steam started I got an error exactly like the error I got before on Kubuntu. While using the Intel card and running Steam I got this error:

```
ERROR: Could not open display :8
```

Nvidia running using bumblebee was giving me a primus error.

I reinstalled the operating system again and installed updates and Steam is working. 
How do I install Bumblebee without getting a graphic cards problem?

Comment: Official Optimus support is out for Linux.

Comment: Optimus support? On 13.04 i was using bumblebee. What change now about this support? Nvidia-primus is not working for me.

Comment: @set4812 Bumblebee by default uses `nvidia-current` driver. If you are using `nvidia-319` you need to change `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf` and restart Bumblebee.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all Bumblebee packages you have installed (along with the nvidia319). Start afresh. Specific instructions for Ubuntu 13.10 version are as follows:
From the [Bumblebee on Ubuntu installation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Basic_Setup) wiki-

"You need to open your terminal and enter the commands below.

If on 12.04.3, replace linux-headers-generic with linux-headers-generic-lts-raring.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
```

Enable the Universe and Multiverse repositories (for bumblebee and nvidia packages respectively).

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install Bumblebee using the default proprietary nvidia driver for 12.04 - 13.04 :

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia virtualgl linux-headers-generic
```

***And for 13.10 :

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic
Reboot*** "
```

First purge the nvidia-319 you have OR update it ( I didn't do either because Bumblebee handled it for me ). Then follow the highlighted instructions for 13.10. 
Then REBOOT( very important ). If it shows an error like :"Not added to the Bumblebee group". Then add yourself using `groupadd`

This should work.